# Render menu based on user, roles and methods

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5

I have a issue with rendering a menu that uses roles and users. Im using Laravel 5.2 (just for info and maybe a easy solution :) )
What im trying to achieve is to get the current user, with the roles which has actions. The problem is: 2 different roles can contain the
same method and i dont want to get them twice but just one time. How can i achieve this easily?

Can someone help me out please?

My table structure:

```
- users
  -- id
  -- email

- roles
  -- role_id
  -- title

- methods
  -- id
  -- title

- users_roles
  -- user_id
  -- role_id

- methods_roles
  -- role_id
  -- method_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you all the methods (**no duplicates**) for the user with `$your_user_id`:

```
select * 
from methods m
inner join methods_roles mr on m.id = mr.method_id
inner join user_roles ur on ur.role_id = mr.role_id
where ur.user_id = $your_user_id
group by m.id
```

Comment: That works like a charm!!! Thank you! One more question: the methods contains "controllers", controllers contains "modules", modules contains "base_path", can i attach those as a multidimensional array?

Comment: This is another problem and you should create another question with it ( after you upvote and accept my answer so that others will know this question already has a solution )